# Access TR of mastepage from Child Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, tablerow

I need to access a `tr` control added in masterpage and make is visible using the childpage.

Following is the code:

```
//MasterPage
<tr runat="server" id="tr_Head" visible="false">
   //other controls
</tr>
```

In my childpage in pageload():

```
//ChildPage
Control cnt = (Control)this.Master.Page.FindControl("tr_Head");
cnt.Visible = true;
```

but at `cnt` I get a null reference exception. How can I make the `tr_Head` visible from my childpage?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself,

it should be accessed like

```
//ChildPage
Control cnt = (Control)Master.FindControl("tr_Head");
cnt.Visible = true;
```